# REST API Best Practice For Accessing Self/Own Objects

Tags: rest, authorization, jwt

Say I'm creating a journaling application and I want users to be able to post entries to their journals.

I do not intend to ever allow a user (even a moderator) to post an entry in someone else's journal.

That said, are there any arguments for exposing the account or journal id in my endpoint path?

I would think that `POST api/journals/postEntry` would be sufficient as I can determine the user via access token or JWT token.

Can anyone think of arguments for providing the journalId in the path? EX: `POST api/journals/{user journalId}/postEntry`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone think of arguments for providing the journalId in the path? EX: POST api/journals/{user journalId}/postEntry

Short answer: it's a violation of the uniform interface constraint.

See [Fielding, 2000](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1).

What you are doing, in effect, is creating this little corner of the world where, instead of using the target-uri to identify a resource, you are instead using target-uri + token.

Which means that your thing doesn't use the semantics that the general purpose components in the world are expecting.

For example, when I copy the URI out of my user agent, and share it with someone else, that other person doesn't get the result I expect -- they end up looking at *their* view, not mine.

The fact that we can stick a URI in an email message and have it just work for the person reading the email is a really big piece in the adoption story.

Furthermore, the [cache constraint](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_4) in REST rather depends on being able to use the identifier as the primary cache key.  So your bespoke identity mechanism has the potential to mess up caching.

IN PRACTICE: you are using HTTP, and HTTP has caching rules that [prohibit sharing authenticated](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-3.2) requests.  So the caching issues mentioned above are purely theoretical.

Alternatives you might consider

- You could arrange for `/api/journals/postEntry` to [redirect](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4) to `/api/journals/{userJournalId}/postEntry`
- You could use the [Content-Location](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.4.2) header to indicate that there is a more specific identifier for the current representation.
- You can use the [canonical link relation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6596) to help clients navigate to the preferred resource from the alternatives.